# Error when creating trees in latex

Tags: forest

So when I am creating trees using forest I get a really weird error when creating the second tree. I get the following error even when I create an empty tree:

> Argument of \bracket@Parse@token has an extra }. \par l.219 \end
> forest

But I have checked that I don't have an extra `}`. Plus when I remove the `\begin` and `\end` for the empty forest tree my code runs perfectly. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: would you like to upload the code

Comment: You make some error in your `forest` tree. Since your code is unknown to us, it is impossible to help you!